# $H\unlhd G$ iff there exists a group $K$ and a homomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow K$ with $H=\ker(\varphi)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $H\subseteq G$ be a non-empty subset. Then $H\unlhd G$ iff there exists a group $K$ and a homomorphism $\varphi:G\rightarrow K$ with $H=\ker(\varphi)$

I am confused as to what I have to show.

Do I need to show that $H$ must equal $\ker(\varphi)$ or is it just that $\exists K,\varphi$ and $H$ with these properties.

Comment: Well, both since one of the properties is that $H=\ker(\varphi)$

Comment: Would using the Corollary: Let $\varphi:G_1\rightarrow G_2$ be a homomorphism. Then $\ker(\varphi)\unlhd G_1$ be sufficient for the ($\Leftarrow$) implication?

Comment: Yes, Dan, it would, since you can then just say $H=\ker(\varphi)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this we note that the set of left cosets $G/H$ is naturally a group with the operation $(gH)*(g'H)=gg'H$. Setting $K=G/H$ and with

$$\varphi:\begin{cases} G\to G/H \\ g\mapsto gH\end{cases}$$

we see that $H\subseteq\ker(\varphi)$ since $H$ is the identity coset in $G/H$, and further if $\varphi(g)=e$ is the identity coset, this means $gH=H$. Since this means that $gh=e$ for some $h\in H$, we see $g=h^{-1}$, and since $H$ is a group, we have $g\in H$, so in fact $\ker(\varphi)\subseteq H$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$Ker( \varphi )$ is normal sub group, also take the homomorphism

$\varphi:G\rightarrow K$ with $H=\ker(\varphi)$

such that $\varphi(a) = aH$